# Cut jQuery Animate Function Short and Revert to Start on Keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a simple dropping ball animation, which I'm using jQuery animate function for. The ball starts at `bottom: 600` and falls until it reaches the ground, at `bottom: 90`.

```
function ballbounce() {
  $('.football').animate({
    'bottom': 90
  }, bouncetime, 'easeOutBounce', function() {

  });
}
```

When the spacebar is pressed, I want to cut the falling animation short and have the ball go up again. I'm trying this by detecting the keypress, getting the current `bottom` value of the ball, adding 300px to that value, then setting it as the new `bottom` value on the ball. But I want the falling animation to resume from that point.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 32: // spacebar
      var ballOffset = $('.football').offset();
      var currentBallPosition  = $(window).height() - ballOffset.top - $('.football').height();
      var newBallPosition = currentBallPosition + 300;
      $('.football').css("bottom", newBallPosition);
    break;

    default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
});
```

I can't get it working, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. The ball's `bottom` is only being updated if I press the spacebar after the animation is complete.

This is for a basic keepy uppy soccer game. So the ball drops and you press spacebar to kick the ball back up in the air again. Is this even a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would call [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) on the element, then reset it to it's original position. You could store the original position as a data attribute on the element itself before the animation then use that to reset it later like this:

```js
function ballbounce(selector,bouncetime) {
  var $ball= $(selector);  
  $ball.data('original-top',$ball.position().top )
  $ball.animate({ top: '+550px'}, bouncetime, "easeOutBounce", function() {
      //animation complete
  });
  return $ball;  
}
var $ballReference=ballbounce('.football',5000);

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  switch(e.which) {
    case 32: // spacebar
          $ballReference.stop().css({top:$ballReference.data('original-top')});
    break;
    default: return; // exit this handler for other keys
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
});
```

```css
.football{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="football"></div>
```